# foreign key and primary key relation in models in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

These models are in two different applications in django. I had created the primary key and foreign key relation between the two tables, but the output is not desired output.

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField( max_length=255, default=None)
    email = models.CharField( max_length=255, default=None)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField( default=0)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField( auto_now=True)

class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField( max_length=255, default=None)
    description = models.CharField( max_length=255, default=None)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey('Account.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Suppose I created a entry in the `User` table and the id assigned is `1`, but I can also create a entry in the `Todo`table with `user_id = 2` (which is not a valid value according to the rule ), and the entry is created. Can any one suggest why?

In Python shell:

```
from Account.models import User
my_user = ( user_name = "Abhis", email = "aa@aa.com", mobile_number = "9999999999", created_on = datetime.datetime.today())
my_user.save()    

# it will create a row with id 1.
from ToDo.models import Todo
my_todo = ( title = "title", description = "description", created_on = datetime.datetime.today(), user_id = 4)
my_todo.save()
# the row with this user_id = 4 is created, which must be illegal
```

Comment: share the code you have written to create objects.

Comment: Actually the field is `user` not `user_id`. And also pls paste the code without any syntax error..

Comment: user_id column is created in the database itself, that's why i m using it

Answer (score 1):

The django documentation states that this will not happen and it will throw DoesNotExist exception. Kindly check the link below

[Django raises DoesNotExist when consulting an empty ForeignKey field or key that does not exist](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12708)

But if you are connecting to a database that exists, and it has values which are not proper foreign keys that is also mentioned in the below link. It clearly states that the model is wrong and should be changed in such a scenario.Link below

[documentation: invalid foreign key and select_related](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18275)

When i tried to assign a random value to a foreign key it threw ValueError. Can you check if your DB does not have an entry with `user_id=4`.